# Issues with upgrading jQuery v2.2.3 to v3.6 using the migrate plugin

Tags: jquery

I am upgrading our existing jQuery framework v2.2.3 to the latest v3.6 using the prescribed jQuery migrate plugin (`jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js`). However, once I include the reference to the migrate file, I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` console error. The location of the error points to the very last character on the bundled and minified .js files.

The order of my referenced files are:

1. jquery.js
2. migrate.js
3. myfile.js

Has anyone experienced a similar issue perhaps? Did you also use the `migrate` plugin, or was something different attempted?

Comment: With minified JS errors like this are often caused by missing `;` line terminators, but without seeing the source this is just a guess. I'd suggest finding the line/character that's causing the error and checking the syntax.

Comment: You guided me in the right direction, I removed the minification of my js files for development purposes. The error disappeared, allowing me to proceed with the updates.